# JavaScript / jQuery stopwatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Just as a learning exercise, I set out making a stopwatch without looking up how to do it etc.

I know it will have been done many times before.  I'm just looking for some feedback on what I should do to make the code more efficient / cleaner / in keeping with standards etc.

[This is the result](http://jsfiddle.net/5wgspdv6/3/)

```
// declare vars
var secondsDiv = $("#seconds");
var minsDiv = $("#mins");
var hoursDiv = $("#hours");
var interval = null;
var timer = false;

// return the value of a given div
function getCurrentValue(value) {
  return value.html();
}

// reset the value of a chosen div to 00
function resetValue(value){
  value.html("00");
}

// check if values are more than 59 to progress the timer
function check59() {
  var currentSec = getCurrentValue(secondsDiv);
  var currentMins = getCurrentValue(minsDiv);
  var currentHours = getCurrentValue(hoursDiv);
  // check the seconds to become a minute
  if (currentSec > 59) {
    currentMins++;
    if (currentMins < 10) {
      minsDiv.html("0" + currentMins);
    } else {
      minsDiv.html(currentMins);
    }
    resetValue(secondsDiv);
  }
  // check the minutes to become an hour
  if (currentMins > 59) {
    currentHours++;
    if (currentHours < 10) {
      hoursDiv.html("0" + currentHours);
    } else {
      hoursDiv.html(currentHours);
    }
    resetValue(minsDiv);
  }
}

// add seconds
function addSecond() {
  var currentSec = getCurrentValue(secondsDiv);
  currentSec++;
  if (currentSec < 10) {
    secondsDiv.html("0" + currentSec);
  } else {
    secondsDiv.html(currentSec);
  }
  check59();
}  

// run the initial addSecond function every second
$("#startTimer").click(function(){
  if (timer===false) {
    timer = true;
    interval = setInterval(addSecond, 1000);
  }
});

// stop the addSecond function every second
$("#pauseTimer").click(function(){
  clearInterval(interval);
  timer = false;
});

// reset all values
$("#clearTimer").click(function(){
  resetValue(secondsDiv);
  resetValue(minsDiv);
  resetValue(hoursDiv);
});
```

Comment: I don't know if you have noticed but when you paus and then start the watch it begins counting from 0.00 instead of where I paused, for instance 0.84. You would probably want to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good! Here's a couple of pointers for you:

It's custom to declare jQuery variables with a `$` prefix. This way it's easy to tell at a glance that it is a element collection. So your top variables would look like this:

```
var $secondsDiv = $("#seconds");
var $minsDiv = $("#mins");
```

Instead of:

> `if (timer===false)`

Consider:

```
if (!timer)
```

If you're looking for legibility there are probably a few other things I'd do differently.

Grouping your variables allows you to make a few shortcuts:

```
var time = {
  seconds: $("#seconds"), 
  minutes: $("#mins"),
  hours:   $("#hours")
}

function getValue(timeStr) {
  return time[timeStr].html();
}

getValue('seconds')
```

And I'm not sure about the `check59()` implementation. I'm sure we could make that more efficient, and reduce the repetition.

But the next step for you is definitely to create a class for this and scope your variables, that way you'll be able to include multiple timers in the same page :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, have tidied up the check59() function slightly and made a function to check if a value is a double digit. Cant think of a way yet to make that bit more efficient. I will be looking to make it into a class soon. Learning PHP classes currently so Javascript will come soon.